# Invalid Json error when Uploading/pushing a file to Azure Devops Repo using Pushes Create Api with Python

Tags: python, git, azure-devops, python-requests, azure-devops-rest-api

I was trying to automate the task of pushing some files to various folder in a repo. I tried using Rest API provided by azure. When using Pushes Create API for the same, from the docs this is the content in the request body

[snapshot of request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAUza.png)

This is the snapshot of python code that I wrote:

[The code that I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl7pJ.png)

In the above code repositeries_url contains the valid API URL.
When I run the code I am getting response code 400 and printing the JSON gives me

{'$id': '1', 'innerException': None, 'message': 'The body of the request contains invalid Json.\r\nParameter name: contentStream', 'typeName': 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer.InvalidArgumentValueException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer', 'typeKey': 'InvalidArgumentValueException', 'errorCode': 0, 'eventId': 0}

Why is this error coming and how can I rectify this error?

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Format them into your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found below mistake in your python code.

In your code, you defined `payload["commits"]` as commits array.

[image]

But you mistakenly assign temp as its value. You need to append temp to `payload["commits"]` array. ie. `payload["commits"].append(temp)`

[image]

Also if you want to use `json` in the request.post method to post the data. You can directly pass the `payload` object. Like below:

`response = requests.post(url = repo_url, json = payload, headers = header)`

Or you can use `data` in  request.post method to post the json string. See below:

`response = requests.post(url = repo_url, data= jsonPayload, headers = header)`

See below full code:

```
....    
temp["changes"].append(aksh)
payload["commits"].append(temp)  ##append temp to commits array
jsonPayload=json.dumps(payload)

#pass payload to json parameter directly
response = requests.post(url = repo_url, json= payload, headers = header)
#you can also use data
#response = requests.post(url = repo_url, data= jsonPayload, headers = header)
```

Comment: Hi @Levi Lu-MSFT, if you could help me out with [my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75834206/azure-devops-exceptions-azuredevopsserviceerror-the-body-of-the-request-contain) that would be great. It seems to be similar, yet different. Thanks in advance for your help!